# Why do you sometimes do two checks on a string?

Tags: c, null-pointer

I saw this code:

```
char *str;
// Some code
if (! str || ! *str)
    return str;
```

Why need to check `! *str`？ Isn't `if (! str)` enough?

Comment: Is `str` a char pointer?

Comment: It depends on what it's supposed to test. Consider `char str[] = "";`.

Comment: @k99  "Why need to check ! *str?" You need not! :) Moreover you even need not to check !str!:) For example Standard C string functions do not do this.:)

Comment: We have no idea why or even if you need to check it since you provide no context.

Comment: You need to provide a bit more context information.. You have 350 reputation, so you should know that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not complete enough to be answered.

Comment: @alk I edited it. I agree with Jabberwocky that a 350 rep user should do better, but since they don't respond, I edited it to the obvious choice. I did it because the question itself is actually a pretty good question.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What happens if the condition is not true? It is not a simple `NULL`-check or some kind of `isEmpty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at a truth table:

```
str    *str    !str   !*str   !str || !*str
T      T       F      F       F
F      T       T      F       T
T      F       F      T       T
F      F       T      T       T
```

So if the `str` is a NULL pointer, then `!str` will be true and `str` is always returned. If `str` is not a NULL pointer, then `str` will only be returned if `*str` is the NUL terminator.

Note that you can use Boolean algebra to rewrite this to `!(str && *str)`. The parenthesis can be expressed in English as "non-empty string". So the whole condition is "not non-empty string".

Note that it work because of *short circuiting* which means that if the result of either `||` or `&&` can be determined by just the left operand, then the right operand will not be evaluated. Otherwise the dereferencing would yield undefined behavior when `str` is a NULL pointer.

Here, there is a quite important logical thing to notice. Just because a string is not "not empty" does not necessarily imply that it is empty. But it depends a bit on the interpretation. There are three cases, and here is an example of all of them.

- `"Hello, World\0"` - Definitely not empty
- `"\0"` - Definitely empty
- `NULL` - Definitely not "not empty", but is it empty?

I might add that this is a pretty weird condition for returning `str`. It's not something you would normally do.

Comment: The function, as specified in the question, checks for 'isEmpty'.

Comment: @dash-o Ehm, no?

Comment: The snippet from the question does not return a `bool`. It also does not return `NULL` if `str[0]==0`

Comment: @Gerhardh Ehm, yes? I said that I rewrote it. The core thing in the question is the actual check.

Comment: OK. Now with your edit you made it clear that you only rewrote the condition, not the whole `if`

Comment: what about string like that “Hello\0World“   “\0HelloWorld“？@klutt

Comment: @k99 By definition, a string ends at the NUL terminator. There isn't anything after it.

Comment: @k99 That's a common confusion. A string is often an array, but not always. And a string literal can contain several strings.

Answer (score 5):

It depend on what you want to check:

- The `!str` check is str is NULL.
- The `!*str` checks that the first char in `str` is NUL byte ('\0')

Combined, they will return 's' if s is NULL, or s point to a NUL char